# How to edit partitions in my computer

Tags: gparted, partitioning

[image: The picture shows the status of my disk,totally messed up]

The above picture,as you might have seen is a lot messed.Now,I would like to express my problem.

Now,what I wanna do is merge all those 3 unallocated spaces into a single drive and then merge it into the Windows drive.How can I do it? Any idea.

Comment: Why do you want these to be added to Windows? Do you want to go through a lot of steps to get just around 6MB? I would say add these unallocated spaces to partitions near them. Saves a lot of work!

Comment: Besides that: You can not. The 1.44 is there to create a boundary between NTFS and ext4. On a disk size like that I would not bother.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly normal to have a few megabytes between partitions (some software do this purposefully, and as some have said, are necessary to have). To remove these few megabytes you will need to move the partitions above the unallocated space down. This will group the unallocated space so that you can combine the space left over into another partition.

For a few megabytes, this is simply not worth it. This would take quite a while (many hours), can put quite alot of wear on the disk, and has the potentiality of data loss, or corruption.

Comment: It's worth adding that the GUI representation of that free space is deceptive, since it exaggerates the amount of free space involved. There's a total of 5.4 MiB of unallocated space in the partition table. The Windows partition (`/dev/sda3`) is 39.07 GiB -- note GiB vs. MiB.  In other words, even if you could add all that space to `/dev/sda3`, you'd increase its size by just 0.0135%. Another way of looking at it: An Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop `.iso` file is 964MiB, so you'd need over 178 times as much space as you'd gain to store an Ubuntu `.iso` file.

Answer (score 1):

Partitions need to be aligned on particular boundaries. Although disk data is referred to in 512 byte sectors, modern drives work on much bigger sectors internally. So having a partition boundary that is not aligned to the disk physical page size can have a very serious performance hit.

This is especially relevant for SSD drives. These have page sizes of 4096 bytes or 8192 bytes.

The gParted software will try and make sure that partitions are aligned so will leave small portions of the disk unused to achieve this.

There is a good discussion of [Partition Alignment](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Partition_Alignment) here.